# cron error Cannot instantiate interface magenot 2

Tags: magento2.2, error, cron

I'm getting the following error on magento cron execution:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Lock\LockManagerInterface in /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#1 /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#3 /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('KiwiCommerce\\Cr...')
#4 /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/ObserverFactory.php(33): Magento\Frame in /home/mywebsite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111
```

What can I do to fix this?

-----UPDATE------

I just discovered that error was caused by an extension that tries to use `\Magento\Framework\Lock\LockManagerInterface` in a constructor.
Here's a sample of the code:

```
namespace KiwiCommerce\CronScheduler\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\Console\Cli;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule;
use Magento\Framework\Profiler\Driver\Standard\Stat;
use Magento\Framework\Profiler\Driver\Standard\StatFactory;

class ProcessCronQueueObserverDefault extends \Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver
{

    private $logger;
    private $state;
    private $scheduleHelper = null;
    private $jobHelper = null;
    private $lockManager;
    private $invalid = [];

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Cron\Model\ScheduleFactory $scheduleFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface $cache,
        \Magento\Cron\Model\ConfigInterface $config,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Console\Request $request,
        \Magento\Framework\ShellInterface $shell,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $dateTime,
        \Magento\Framework\Process\PhpExecutableFinderFactory $phpExecutableFinderFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
        StatFactory $statFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Lock\LockManagerInterface $lockManager,
        \KiwiCommerce\CronScheduler\Helper\Schedule $scheduleHelper,
        \KiwiCommerce\CronScheduler\Helper\Cronjob $jobHelper
    ) {

        $construct= "__construct"; // in order to bypass the compiler
        parent::$construct($objectManager, $scheduleFactory, $cache, $config, $scopeConfig, $request, $shell, $dateTime, $phpExecutableFinderFactory, $logger, $state, $statFactory, $lockManager);
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->lockManager = $lockManager;
        $this->scheduleHelper = $scheduleHelper;
        $this->jobHelper = $jobHelper;
    }
```

Still don't know how to fix it though.

---- extension di.xml ------

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver" type="KiwiCommerce\CronScheduler\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver" />
</config>
```

Comment: In case your interface still won't be loaded, check your di.xml and validate that a preference is available.

Comment: @AasimGoriya can you explain in details, what am I looking for exactly in di.xml file?

Comment: can you please add your di.xml here ?

Comment: You could also ask KiwiCommerce support about this error in their module, maybe they have an update or a fix.

Comment: this is core di.xml which is not needed, please add your custom module's di.xml which is located on your module's /etc/ directory

Comment: I'm posting it in question description

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could also ask KiwiCommerce support about this error in their module, maybe they have an update or a fix.

They share their phone and e-mail on their official website.

Comment: I have checked these things, but the solution is somewhere else

Comment: Hm, it really looks like a permission issue... Check also if every permissions are good in `/var/` folder. If they are... Maybe i'm wrong finally :)

Comment: please see my question update

Answer (score 0):

*Remove file in KiwiCommerce\CronScheduler\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserverDefault.inc file and put below code in ProcessCronQueueObserver.php*

```
<?php
namespace KiwiCommerce\CronScheduler\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\Console\Cli;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule;

class ProcessCronQueueObserver extends \Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver{

private $logger;
private $state;
private $scheduleHelper = null;
private $jobHelper = null;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Cron\Model\ScheduleFactory $scheduleFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface $cache,
    \Magento\Cron\Model\ConfigInterface $config,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Console\Request $request,
    \Magento\Framework\ShellInterface $shell,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $dateTime,
    \Magento\Framework\Process\PhpExecutableFinderFactory $phpExecutableFinderFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
    \KiwiCommerce\CronScheduler\Helper\Schedule $scheduleHelper,
    \KiwiCommerce\CronScheduler\Helper\Cronjob $jobHelper
) {
    $construct= "__construct"; // in order to bypass the compiler
    parent::$construct($objectManager, $scheduleFactory, $cache, $config, 
    $scopeConfig, $request, $shell, $dateTime, $phpExecutableFinderFactory, 
    $logger, $state);
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->state = $state;
    $this->scheduleHelper = $scheduleHelper;
    $this->jobHelper = $jobHelper;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    #Handle Fatal Error
    $runningSchedule = null;
    register_shutdown_function(function () use (&$runningSchedule) {
        $errorMessage = error_get_last();
        if ($errorMessage) {
            if ($runningSchedule != null) {
                $s = $runningSchedule;
                $s->setStatus(\Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule::STATUS_ERROR);
                $s->setErrorMessage($errorMessage['message']);
                $s->setErrorFile($errorMessage['file']);
                $s->setErrorLine($errorMessage['line']);
                $s->save();
            }
        }
    });

    $pendingJobs = $this->_getPendingSchedules();
    $currentTime = $this->dateTime->gmtTimestamp();
    $jobGroupsRoot = $this->_config->getJobs();

    $phpPath = $this->phpExecutableFinder->find() ?: 'php';

    foreach ($jobGroupsRoot as $groupId => $jobsRoot) {
        $this->_cleanup($groupId);
        $this->_generate($groupId);
        if ($this->_request->getParam('group') !== null
            && $this->_request->getParam('group') !== '\'' . ($groupId) . '\''
            && $this->_request->getParam('group') !== $groupId
        ) {
            continue;
        }
        if (($this->_request->getParam(self::STANDALONE_PROCESS_STARTED) !== '1') && (
                $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    'system/cron/' . $groupId . '/use_separate_process',
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                ) == 1
            )
        ) {
            $this->_shell->execute(
                $phpPath . ' %s cron:run --group=' . $groupId . ' --' . Cli::INPUT_KEY_BOOTSTRAP . '='
                . self::STANDALONE_PROCESS_STARTED . '=1',
                [
                    BP . '/bin/magento'
                ]
            );
            continue;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule $schedule */
        foreach ($pendingJobs as $schedule) {
            $runningSchedule = $schedule;
            $jobConfig = isset($jobsRoot[$schedule->getJobCode()]) ? $jobsRoot[$schedule->getJobCode()] : null;
            if (!$jobConfig) {
                continue;
            }

            $scheduledTime = strtotime($schedule->getScheduledAt());
            if ($scheduledTime > $currentTime) {
                continue;
            }

            try {
                if ($schedule->tryLockJob()) {
                    $this->scheduleHelper->setPid($schedule);
                    $cpu_before = getrusage();
                    $this->_runJob($scheduledTime, $currentTime, $jobConfig, $schedule, $groupId);
                    $cpu_after = getrusage();
                    $this->scheduleHelper->setCpuUsage($cpu_after, $cpu_before, $schedule);
                    $this->scheduleHelper->setMemoryUsage($schedule);
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $schedule->setMessages($e->getMessage());
                $schedule->setErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                $schedule->setErrorLine($e->getLine());

                if ($schedule->getStatus() === Schedule::STATUS_ERROR) {
                    $this->logger->critical($e);
                }
                if ($schedule->getStatus() === Schedule::STATUS_MISSED
                    && $this->state->getMode() === State::MODE_DEVELOPER
                ) {
                    $this->logger->info(
                        sprintf(
                            "%s Schedule Id: %s Job Code: %s",
                            $schedule->getMessages(),
                            $schedule->getScheduleId(),
                            $schedule->getJobCode()
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
            $schedule->save();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @param string $jobCode
 * @param string $cronExpression
 * @param int $timeInterval
 * @param array $exists
 * @return void
 */
protected function saveSchedule($jobCode, $cronExpression, $timeInterval, $exists)
{
    $result = $this->jobHelper->isJobActive($jobCode);

    if ($result) {
        parent::saveSchedule($jobCode, $cronExpression, $timeInterval, $exists);
    }
}}
```